# How to communicate pt2262 and pt2272 modul

Tags: arduino-uno, wireless, rf

[image: This is my receiver 2272 modul]

[image: This is my tranmistter 2262 modul]

There is a library called Virtual wire. I used it, but without success. I couldn't quite understand its pins. Can you explain? How can I use it?First picture receiver(pc2272) second picture tranmitter(pc2262 module ı used)

Comment: please add the information that you are looking at ... explain what part you do not understand

Comment: For example, there are 4 channels. How will I use each of these channels? In some places, the receiver assumes that the data is received when the pin to which the receiver is connected is HIGH. Is this true? I couldn't understand how it works in general

Comment: Also .What is the difference nrf24l01?

Comment: wbere are you seeing this information? ... add all info to the question ... please use the edit button to add it